# flutter : How to make Card in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want to make Card SomeThing Like This.

[image]

Can anyone help me.

Comment: You should be used ListTile Widget is same as like your design

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil But how to add all Field like name, date etc

Comment: You may want to get a closer look at the Card widget : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html

Comment: You can learn something then you know `how to` https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented your requirement by using 'Card' widget.

[image]

```
/// Flutter code sample for Card

// This sample shows creation of a [Card] widget that shows album information
// and two actions.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
                ),
              ),
              child: Icon(Icons.album),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Name'),
                        Text('Price'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Date'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Quantity: 3'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Total Amount'),
                        Text('Rs. 253'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.

```
class MyCardWidget extends StatelessWidget { 
  MyCardWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

more: https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-card

Answer (score 0):

> You can make a clickable card using GestureDetector.
> We have created a very simple and basic card here, you can add your
> desired changes to it and use it in your codes.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CardItem extends StatefulWidget {
  CardItem({ super.key });

  @override
  State<CardItem> createState() => _CardItemState();
}

class _CardItemState extends State<CardItem> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      print('object');
    },
    child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/orange.jpg',
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 72,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 28,
                        left: 15,
                        right: 15
                       ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      color: const Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 0.7),
                    ),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 9,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: const [
                            Text(
                              'Orange Juice',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 17,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 58, 54, 54),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '35 Cal',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 13.5,
                                fontFamily: 'YekanRegular',
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 58, 54, 54),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}}
```